# Continuous functions with closed sets proof

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The question is as follows:

> Let $f:E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where  $E\subset \mathbb{R}$.  The function $f$ is continuous if and only if $\forall$ closed sets $A\subset \mathbb{R}, \exists$ a closed set $B\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(A)=B   \cap E.$

I proved this for the same question but with open sets.  I started with the fact that $$\exists  \ \epsilon _{x} > 0   \ \ \ \ \text{such that} \ \ \ \ 
N_{\epsilon _{x}}(f(x)) \subset A.$$
Since $f$ is continuous, 
$$\exists \  \delta _{x}> 0  \ \ \ \ \text{such that} \ \ \ \  N_{\delta _{x}}(x)\cap E\subset f^{-1}(N_{\epsilon _{x}}(f(x)).$$
Hence 
$$B\equiv \bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}(A)}^{ } N_{\delta _{x}}(x) \ \ \ \text{is open.}$$
Therefore we can conclude 
$$f^{-1}(A) \subset \bigcup_{x \in f^{-1}(A)}^{ } N_{\delta _{x}}(x)\cap E = B\cap E\subset f^{-1}(A).$$
So, $f^{-1}(A)=B   \cap E.$  And proving the other way around is similar.

For the question I am trying to answer, I am trying to use the same idea just with the notion of closed sets.  However, I am stuck.  I think I will have to somehow integrate the complement of the set $A$ into the proof in one way or another, and then make a conclusion.  I am still not sure.

Finally, can this even be proved in a similar manner? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Am I right in guessing $E = D$?

Comment: Sorry- I wrote $D$ instead of $E$.  I will change that!

Comment: Complement  (related to the word "complete") not compliment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your results for open sets, the
closed set proposition is simple.

Assume f is continuous.
If K is closed, then R - K is open.
Thus f$^{-1}$(R - K) = R - f$^{-1}$(K)) = R is open.
Hence f$^{-1}$(K)) is closed.

Use the same method to show if the inverse images of
closed sets are closed, then the function is continuous.